# How to remove duplicate lines in YAML format configuration files?

Tags: unix, duplicates, yaml

I have a bunch of manifest/yaml files that may or may not have these key value pair duplicates:

```
...
app: activity-worker
app: activity-worker
...
```

I need to search through each of those files and find those duplicates so that I can remove one of them.

Note: I know that to replace a certain string (say, switch `service:` to `app:`) in all files of a directory (say, `dev`) I can run `grep -l 'service:' dev/* | xargs sed -i "" 's/\service:/app:/g'`. I'm looking for a relation between lines.

Comment: Please provide more context and some examples of what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: @bishop okay I'm open to any other way

Comment: Only thing I've tried to figure out is how to find the duplicate lines. I've tried `sort fileName | uniq -d` but this command showed me a little more than the duplicate lines I needed.

Comment: Sorry @John. I've changed my question description, hopefully it's more clear?

Comment: `awk '!seen[$0]++' config.yaml`?

Comment: There is no such regex. You're looking for a relation between lines, not a pattern in a single line.

Comment: I have focused your question's title and tags; and removed the please and thank you noise. You may roll these edits back if they do not match your intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you call YAML, is not YAML. The YAML specification 
[very explicitly states](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#mapping//) that
keys in a mapping must be unique, and your keys are not:

> The content of a mapping node is an unordered set of key: value node
>     pairs, with the restriction that each of the keys is unique. YAML
>     places no further restrictions on the nodes. In particular, keys may
>     be arbitrary nodes, the same node may be used as the value of
>     several key: value pairs, and a mapping could even contain itself as
>     a key or a value (directly or indirectly).

On the other hand some libraries have implemented this incorrectly, choosing to overwrite
any previous value associated with a key, with a later value. In your case, since 
the values are the same, which value would be taken doesn't really matter.

Also your block style representation is not the only way to represent key-value pairs of a 
mapping in "YAML", these duplicates could also be represented in a mapping, as

```
{...., app: activity-worker, app: activity-worker, .... }
```

With the two occurences not necessarily being next to each, nor on the same line. The
following is also **semantically equivalent** "YAML" to your input:

```
{...., app: activity-worker, app: 
       activity-worker, .... }
```

If you have such faulty "YAML" files, the best way to clean them up is
using the round-trip capabilities of
[`ruamel.yaml`](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (disclaimer: I
am the author of that package), and its ability to switch except/warn
on faulty input containing duplicate keys. You can install it for your
Python (virtual environment) using:

```
pip install ruamel.yaml
```

Assuming your file is called `input.yaml` and it contains:

```
a: 1   # some duplicate keys follow
app: activity-worker
app: activity-worker
b: "abc"
```

You can run the following one-liner:

```
python -c "import sys; from ruamel.yaml import YAML; yaml = YAML(); yaml.preserve_quotes=yaml.allow_duplicate_keys=True; yaml.dump(yaml.load(open('input.yaml')), sys.stdout)"
```

to get:

```
a: 1   # some duplicate keys follow
app: activity-worker
b: "abc"
```

and if your input were like:

```
{a: 1, app: activity-worker, app: 
    activity-worker, b: "abc"}
```

the output would be:

```
{a: 1, app: activity-worker, b: "abc"}
```

Comment: Thanks for a very thorough, informative answer Anthon!

Comment: @v1mg1rl If this solves your problem, please accept this answer by clicking the checkmark (✓) next to the top of this answer. That way others know your question has a working answer (without having to scroll to the comments). That also marks your question as answered in queries.